# How Do I Proxy Requests for Rsocket on React app

Tags: reactjs, websocket, rsocket

I need to proxy both rsocket and http in react app. I was successful adding proxy to http request by adding to package json

```
"proxy": "http://192.184.24.12:82"
```

How do I do it to rsocket that sits on top of websocket.

Need to work http and rsocket simultaneously

```
let client = new RSocketClient({
    transport: new RSocketWebSocketClient(
        {
            url: "ws://localhost:7000/ws",
            wsCreator: (url) => new WebSocket(url),
            debug: true,
        },
        BufferEncoders
    ),
    setup: {
        dataMimeType: "application/json",
        metadataMimeType: MESSAGE_RSOCKET_COMPOSITE_METADATA.string,
        keepAlive: 5000,
        lifetime: 60000,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use rsocket in browser - then you use a websocket transport underneath. That said, if your proxy can proxy websocket (and I bet it can) you can proxy rsocket